# HTML website not showing up after adding a section

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a website with HTML, CSS, and React. The previous version displays fine but when I try to add another section called "Experience" nothing but the background gray color shows up. I think it might be a problem with either importing React-Chrono or importing this section to make it link with the rest of the website but I'm not sure. This is the section I am trying to add:

```js
import React from "react"
  import { Chrono } from "react-chrono";

  const Experience = () => {
    const items = [{
      title: "May 1940",
      cardTitle: "Dunkirk",
      url: "http://www.history.com",
      cardSubtitle:"Men of the British Expeditionary Force (BEF) wade out to..",
      cardDetailedText: "Men of the British Expeditionary Force (BEF) wade out to..",
      media: {
        type: "IMAGE",
        source: {
          url: "http://someurl/image.jpg"
        }
      }
    },]

    return (
      <div id="experience" className="w-full flex justify-center overflow-hidden-web">
      <div className="w-full xl:w-[70%] flex flex-col pb-16">
        <div className="w-full">
          <SectionTitle title="EXPERIENCE" subtitle="What I've Done Before" />
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "400px" }}>
          <Chrono items={items} />
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default Experience;
```

This is how I am adding each section:
(All of the other sections display fine until Experience is added)

```js
import NavBar from "../Components/nav/NavBar";
import Hero from "../Pages/Hero";
import Projects from "../Pages/Projects";
import About from "../Pages/About";
import Experience from "../Pages/Experience";
import Skills from "../Pages/Skills";
import Contact from "../Pages/Contact";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Hero />
      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Projects />
      <Skills />
      <Contact />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As a reference, here is what another section looks like that works:

```js
import SectionTitle from "../Components/SectionTitle";
import ProjectCards from "../Components/ProjectCards";

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <div id="projects" className="w-full overflow-hidden-web flex justify-center">
      <div className="w-full min-h-[800px] h-screen xl:w-[70%] relative mt-40 flex flex-col items-center justify-center pb-36">
        <div className="w-full h-[180%] mt-[-10%] mb-[-10%]">
          <SectionTitle title="PROJECTS" subtitle="What I have done so far" />
        </div>
        <div className="w-full h-[70%] z-10 flex justify-center">
          <div className="w-full xl:w-[70%] h-[-10%">
            <ProjectCards />
          </div>
          <div className="absolute w-full h-full top-[100%] right-[-75%] sm:right-[-50%]">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

I am new to React so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your issue can't be found without seeing running result. I want to check your full code. Share me github url. I can help you.

Comment: Most useful if it's shared here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you get anything in the devtools console?